# How do I use the MultipleTextOutputFormat using the new Hadoop API?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to write multiple output files. 
How do I do this using Job instead of JobConf?

Answer (score 1):

an easy way to to create key based output file names

```
 input data type

  //key        //value
 cupertino   apple
 sunnyvale   banana
 cupertino   pear
```

MultipleTextOutputFormat class

```
static class KeyBasedMultipleTextOutputForma extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String name) {
        return key.toString() + "/" + name;
    }
}
```

job config

```
 job.setOutputFormat(KeyBasedMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
```

Run this code and you’ll see the following files in HDFS, where /output is the job output directory:

```
 $ hadoop fs -ls /output
 /output/cupertino/part-00000
 /output/sunnyvale/part-00000
```

hopes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say to use [`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) instead.

Below is a snippet of code that uses MultipleOutputs. Unfortunately I didn't write it and haven't spent much time with it... So I don't know exactly why things are where. I share with the hopes it helps. :)

Job Setup

```
job.setJobName("Job Name");
job.setJarByClass(ETLManager.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(MyThing.class);
job.setMapperClass(MyThingMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyThingReducer.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, Constants.MyThing_NAMED_OUTPUT, TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
job.setInputFormatClass(MyInputFormat.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(conf.get("input")));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(String.format("%s/%s", conf.get("output"), Constants.MyThing_NAMED_OUTPUT)));
```

Reducer Setup

```
public class MyThingReducer extends
    Reducer<Text, MyThing, NullWritable, NullWritable> {
    private MultipleOutputs     m_multipleOutputs;

     @Override
    public void setup(Context context) {
        m_multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        if (m_multipleOutputs != null) {
            m_multipleOutputs.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MyThing> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (MyThing myThing : values) {
            m_multipleOutputs.write(Constants.MyThing_NAMED_OUTPUT, EMPTY_KEY, generateData(context, myThing), generateFileName(context, myThing));
            context.progress();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added link to MultipleOutputs.

Comment: I would like to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat because of it's dynamic creation of the output files. Using MultipleOutputs, I have to manually create a named output for every output file.

Comment: @zzztimbo: You have to use `JobConf` to use `MultipleTextOutputFormat`

Comment: My requirement is that I need to use Job.

Comment: @zzztimbo: Then you'll need to use a Output format that works with job. The only one I know of for `Job` is `MultipleOutputs`.

Comment: @Nija, I am actually encountering the exact same problem and I was hoping you could point me at the link for where you got the code snipper in question from.

Comment: @chuck taylor: added link to post. Most of that comes from my source code. The link I added is pretty good as well.

Comment: @Nija  how to visit JobConf in MultipleTextOutputFormat 's generateFileNameForKeyValue method?