# Control the MultipleOutputFormat files sub-path

Tags: hadoop

I need to control the sub-path of the different different files being managed by MultipleOutputFormat based on the reducer key.

I basically want to set the sub path of the file based on the key given to the reducer.

I can changed the file name by overwrting the generateFileNameForKeyValue method of MultipleOutputFormatbut how can I also change the sub-path of these files?

I mean with just overriding the generateFileNameForKeyValue, I get

```
mySetJobConfigOutputPath/fileNameBasedKey1.dat
                        /fileNameBasedKey2.dat
                        /fileNameBasedKey3.dat
                        ...
```

but I want to make it to be organize files like below

```
 mySetJobConfigOutputPath/path0ConfiguredInsideReducerBasedOnKey/fileNameBasedKey1.dat

                         /path1ConfiguredInsideReducerBasedOnKey/fileNameBasedKey2.dat
                                                                /fileNameBasedKey3.dat

                         /path2ConfiguredInsideReducerBasedOnKey/fileNameBasedKey8.dat
```

as seen, the sub-path and the file name are both figured out by the key inside the reducer.

I know how to configure the file name but was wondering if I can configure the sub-path of the each file under the mySetJobConfigOutputPath folder?

Comment: try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272307/how-do-i-use-the-multipletextoutputformat-using-the-new-hadoop-api#26756067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that that I can override the ***getInputFileBasedOutputFileName*** method also and give it the sub-Path in there.

```
@Override
protected String getInputFileBasedOutputFileName(JobConf conf, String Name)
{
     //your logic goes here. Simply addd the sub path to the name and return    
}
```

You should still implement the ***generateFileNameForKeyValue*** to convert your lead file name to the key

UPDATE: Basically this explains it all http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat